# Not able to detect secondary monitor in Centos 8 GTX 1660TI on a laptop

Tags: centos, gnome, nvidia

Tried installing Nvidia drivers but it caused my laptop to get stuck in "Started Gnome Display" loop where i didn't have access to the TTY.

Comment: How did you install the NVidia drivers?

Comment: I followed this guide: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-centos-8

Comment: Yeah, sadly a lot of sites on the internet provide bad advice like that. The .run executable from nvidia.com often leaves you in this situation, particularly after a kernel update. Eventually, elrepo will have packages for nvidia in el8, but until then, you can uninstall the .run drivers by re-running it with —uninstall.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling the os, how would you suggest I install the drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the NVidia packages from RPMFusion, here are the instructions:

https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration

Make sure to follow the instructions for CentOS8 or RHEL8, there are extra steps.

Then install the kmod-nvidia package.